# Pronunciation of こんばんは?

Tags: words, pronunciation, greetings, conversations, morae

Konbanwa, spelled Konbanha, is a greeting used in the evening. It is pronounced *ko-m-ba-n-wa.*

I don't know if it's my hearing, but to me, the second *n* is silent. Sometimes I hear it as *ko-m-báo-wa* instead of *ko-m-ba-n-wa.*

Is this a speaking preference or a false assumption of mine? Thanks!

Comment: Now that you mention it, it quite often becomes something like こんばっわ

Answer (score 2):

This [discussion](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/n-sound-in-konbanwa.3028130/) might help.  I think the *n* that you're not hearing is just being nasalized instead.